# How to protect user authentification without SSL?

Tags: php, android, authentication, ssl

I'm building an Android cloud app that asks the user to authenticate himself on a remote PHP/MySql server. As for now, I'm using a basic http post request to do so. I understand this is dangerous, since anyone can sniff the communication and steal the credentials. Is there any other solution than to use https/SSL to solve this?

If I have to use SSL, is there a session management library I can use as to not need to resend the user credentials over SSL each time the user contacts the server?

Comment: Use SSL it is cake and otherwise you would be reinventing the wheel. You don't need to send credentials more then once unless the users session times out. Session support is native to [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Comment: Do you mean I could store the username/password on the PHP side like this: $_SESSION['uname']='UNAME'; $_SESSION['pswd']='PSWD'? But then when would I know when to send the credentials when the session times out?

Comment: SSL costs a few dollars. Pony up.

Comment: SSL's free... people just want to make you think it costs money by putting insecure website errors on sites that are 'perfectly' secure. Anyway the server should let the client know that there has been a timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that even if you get a secure authentication all the other stuff will still be vulnerable to sniffing. HTML files are sent back in plain text, which may contain sensitive information. SSL is *made* specifically for this job.

You don't need to resend the credentials, SSL is fairly transparent "plug and play".

Use the PHPSESSID (default for `session_start()`) to keep track of the user.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer should help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947221/secure-authentication-without-ssl). A few good answers in there. In a nutshell: you have some options but it's still best to use SSL.